# Are the tables stored with MEMORY engine recoverable from cluster crash?

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster

I have set up MySQL NDB Cluster 7.3.5 and the cluster was working fine.

Cluster with 4 nodes :

NodeA : SQLNode1, DataNode1

NodeB : SQLNode2, DataNode2

NodeC : Mgmt Node1

NodeD : Mgmt Node2

To test the server reboot scenario I rebooted VMWare ESXi and restarted all VMs.

But the data nodes are subsequently failing to start.

Adding logs for the servers respectively:

/home/mysql/mysqlcluster_data/1/ndb_1_out.log (Data Node 1)

```
error: [ code: 708 line: 38848236 node: 1 count: 1 status: 32687 key: 445914048 name: 'hhmefep/def/fgvmev0000000000-elog-1398414831' ] 
2014-05-13 13:16:40 [ndbd] INFO -- Failed to recreate object 505 during restart, error 708. 
2014-05-13 13:16:40 [ndbd] INFO -- DBDICT (Line: 4688) 0x00000000 
2014-05-13 13:16:40 [ndbd] INFO -- Error handler restarting system 
2014-05-13 13:16:40 [ndbd] INFO -- Error handler shutdown completed - exiting 
2014-05-13 13:16:40 [ndbd] ALERT -- Angel detected too many startup failures(3), not restarting again 
2014-05-13 13:16:40 [ndbd] ALERT -- Node 1: Forced node shutdown completed. Occured during startphase 4. Caused by error 2355: 'Failure to restore schema(Resource configuration error). Permanent error, external action needed'.
```

It seems that the nodes are failing to recover this table: 
hhmefep.fgvmev0000000000-elog-1398414831

---

/home/mysql/mysqlcluster_data/2/ndb_2_out.log (Data Node 2)

```
2014-05-13 13:05:48 [ndbd] INFO -- Start phase 1 completed 
2014-05-13 13:05:48 [ndbd] INFO -- Start phase 2 completed 
2014-05-13 13:05:48 [ndbd] INFO -- Start phase 3 completed 
2014-05-13 13:05:51 [ndbd] INFO -- Node 1 disconnected 
2014-05-13 13:05:51 [ndbd] INFO -- QMGR (Line: 3308) 0x00000000 
2014-05-13 13:05:51 [ndbd] INFO -- Error handler restarting system 
2014-05-13 13:05:51 [ndbd] INFO -- Error handler shutdown completed - exiting 
2014-05-13 13:05:51 [ndbd] ALERT -- Angel detected too many startup failures(3), not restarting again 
2014-05-13 13:05:51 [ndbd] ALERT -- Node 2: Forced node shutdown completed. Occured during startphase 4. Caused by error 2308: 'Another node failed during system restart, please investigate error(s) on other node(s)(Restart error). Temporary error, restart node'.
```

---

It seems that data node 2 is trying to sync with data node 1 but has been forcefully shutdown by management node.

---

(Mgmt Node)

```
ndb_mgm> Node 1: Forced node shutdown completed, restarting. Occured during startphase 4. Caused by error 2355: 'Failure to restore schema(Resource configuration error). Permanent error, external action needed'. 
Node 1: Forced node shutdown completed, restarting. Occured during startphase 4. Caused by error 2355: 'Failure to restore schema(Resource configuration error). Permanent error, external action needed'. 
Node 1: Forced node shutdown completed. Occured during startphase 4. Caused by error 2355: 'Failure to restore schema(Resource configuration error). Permanent error, external action needed'. 
Node 2: Forced node shutdown completed, restarting. Occured during startphase 4. Caused by error 2308: 'Another node failed during system restart, please investigate error(s) on other node(s)(Restart error). Temporary error, restart node'. 
Node 2: Forced node shutdown completed, restarting. Occured during startphase 4. Caused by error 2355: 'Failure to restore schema(Resource configuration error). Permanent error, external action needed'. 

ndb_mgm> Node 2: Forced node shutdown completed. Occured during startphase 4. Caused by error 2355: 'Failure to restore schema(Resource configuration error). Permanent error, external action needed'.
```

---

Please help me on this since it is very frustrating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [MySQL memory engine page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/memory-storage-engine.html):

> The MEMORY storage engine (formerly known as HEAP) creates
>   special-purpose tables with contents that are stored in memory.
>   **Because the data is vulnerable to crashes, hardware issues, or power
>   outages, only use these tables as temporary work areas or read-only
>   caches** for data pulled from other tables.